# Running docker from .netcore using process.start throws error

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, process

I am trying to execute docker through processStartInfo. While trying I am getting error

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
             WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\",
             FileName = "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker",
             RedirectStandardOutput = true,
             RedirectStandardError = true,
             UseShellExecute = false,
             Arguments = arguments
    };
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
```

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not
>   a valid application for this OS platform.'

Comment: use double quotes?

Comment: @vasily.sib and escape the backslashes.

Comment: also, nobody ever try to read exception messages :( _"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."_ means that specified executable is not a valid application for windows. Shouldn't it be `docker.exe` or `docker.bat`?

Comment: @vasily.sib The extension was missing. Solved. Thanks